# CssClass Property not avaliable in Div Tag

Tags: asp.net, css

I am jsut wondering why the CssClass="blah" is not avaliable inside my div tags when style="blah" works.

Is this not part of CSS? Is there a way to set this up? Can I give...

```
<div class="foo">

</div>
```

and set the inline css to...

```
#div foo{blah}
```

or something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the class to you div correctly:

```
<div class="foo">

</div>
```

But in your CSS, you are using the id identifier (#) instead of the class identifier (.):

```
/* This would match any <foo> element with a parent that has an id of div
   for example <span id="div"><foo>...</foo></span> */
#div foo{blah}

/* This matches <div class="foo"> */
div.foo { blah }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can absolutely do that. `CssClass` is a asp.net server-side controls (only) property. It translates to html's standard attribute `class` when rendered to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

CssClass is a .net server side property.  You would need to set `ruant="server"` on the `<div>` tag to use this.  Or you can just use `class="foo"` like you have.

```
<div runat="server" CssClass="foo">

</div>
```

Comment: like this?  #div leftColumn{width:190px; border:1px solid green; float:left;} then... <div class="leftColumn" runat="server" cssclass="leftColumn" >??

Answer (score 0):

First CssClass is a .NET construct only.  HTML does not know anything about CssClass.  A  element can only have a class="foo foo1 foo2" value assigned to it.  As for for your CSS selector you need to switch it to:

```
div#foo { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

I wouldn't really consider it "inline css" as that usually refers to a situation like this:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid gray; background-color: white;">My Div Content</div>
```

Here is a list of all the attributes and events a div element can contain:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp